# Disable HTTP cache in WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, http-caching

In `Spring Boot MVC` app I disable HTTP cache this way:

```
WebContentInterceptor cacheInterceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
cacheInterceptor.setCacheSeconds(0);
cacheInterceptor.setUseExpiresHeader(true);
cacheInterceptor.setUseCacheControlHeader(true);
cacheInterceptor.setUseCacheControlNoStore(true);
registry.addInterceptor(cacheInterceptor);
```

How to do it in `Spring Boot WebFlux` app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot and you'd like to prevent caching for static resources, you can achieve that with the following configuration property:

```
spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store=true
```

If you'd like to disable caching for **everything**, including REST calls and views, etc; then you can implement a custom `WebFilter` that does just that and expose it as a bean in your application:

```
class NoStoreWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders()
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore().getHeaderValue());
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to change `setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore())` to `setCacheControl("no-store")`, because this method is accepting `String` and `CacheControl#toString` is not implemented.

Comment: I guess `spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store` should be `spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store`? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.7/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store